# kendo mobile view load complete

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui

I have map that is not showing and a div height value showing to null when I'm showing a view using kendo mobile .
I want to run a function when a view load complete to show map and calculate a div height can anybody help thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm stuck in a similar problem, I need to accomplish the same without using data attributes

Answer (score 0):

Use the **show** event of the mobile view . show event is fired when the view becomes visible.

```
<div data-role="view" data-show="showMap">

<script>
function showMap() {
///code to display map when view becomes visible
}
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to accomplish this without data-attributes? 

I'm working on an app which has atleast 40 different views and changing the markup is a messy business, considering we might add new views every now and then. 

I want to listen to this event for every view.